# Capture biometric from multiple biometric devices connected through USB port to laptop using javascript

Tags: reactjs, web, usb

I have been trying to capture multiple biometric input using react. I have used WebUSB API to find and get the device details

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const PortCheckPage = () => {
  const [mfs100Devices, setMfs100Devices] = useState([]);

  const listUSBDevices = async () => {
    try {
      const usbDevices = await navigator.usb.getDevices();

      // Filter and store all connected "mfs100" devices
      const mfs100ConnectedDevices = usbDevices.filter(device => device.productName === "MFS100");

      setMfs100Devices(mfs100ConnectedDevices);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error listing USB devices:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check for "mfs100" devices when the component mounts
    listUSBDevices();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>USB Device Status:</h1>
      {mfs100Devices.length > 0 ? (
        <ul>
          {mfs100Devices.map((device, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <strong>Device:</strong> {device.productName}
              <br />
              <strong>Vendor ID:</strong> {device.vendorId}
              <br />
              <strong>Product ID:</strong> {device.productId}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <div>No "mfs100" devices are connected.</div>
      )}
      {/* Your other components and JSX here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PortCheckPage;
```

but when I connect 2 same devices I cannot access particular device because both the device has same ID's.

Im just tryig to access multiple biometric devices simultaneously.Im just stuck in this for few days , can anyone tell me how to achieve this if not what is the solution.

Note:Each of these biometric devices will have a unique serial no, which can be identified by sending a get request to mfs100/info route